# Publishing a DotNetCore tool for multiple platforms

Tags: .net, .net-core, publish

I've written a fairly simple command-line tool in Dotnet-core. It does some fileIO and calls some web-APIs. I want to publish it in binary form for multiple platforms. I was thinking it could be a NuGet package. But I'm stuck at building the publishable binaries.

When I run "dotnet publish"
the output folder contains only DLLs.

When I run "dotnet publish --runtime win7-x64" for example
the output folder does contain an executable. However, it also seems to include about 67MB of DLLs and other binaries from assemblies/namespaces I'm quite certain I'm not using. (Maybe I'm using them indirectly?)

I can swap 'win7-x64' for other platforms like ubuntu or osx. The commands work and the generated output does execute properly on those platforms. I'm just not all that eager to ship that many MB's for a tool that's maybe just 300 lines of code. It feels like I'm using the framework incorrectly.

How do I publish my tool in a binary format and compact way?

Thanks in advance!
-Ben

Answer (score 1):

You've chosen the Self-contained option. In this case, the 67 MB contains the entire .NET core framework, There is also the option to deploy the app without all of .NET framework. But the target system must have .NET core installed on it. I think they are going to add another option to deploy to a single executable that is tree shaken and its size would be smaller in .NET Core 3.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

If your tools is for developers, you can publish it as a .NET global tool: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools-how-to-create

Comment: It's worth mentioning that "Global Tools are framework-dependent applications, which means they rely on a .NET Core runtime installed on your machine" [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools#use-the-tool). In other words, they wont bring the 60+ MB runtime.